# HOW to select any row using primary key in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and sql , I am using this table 
[image]
so it has one serial column `user_id` which is used as primary key (auto_increament). now if user want to delete his profile , i am using

```
<?php
$sql='DELETE FROM userinfo WHERE user_name="'.$_SESSION["username"].'"';
?>
```

Its working fine.`$_SESSION["username"]`is the name of user who is looged in. . and username are unique as well. But now what is the use of primary key , how i can use that corrosponding primary key to delete the `username`. This is just one example. I have comment table now if user delete a comment i have to define 'blog_name','username','comment_time' then it selects the desire comment which i want to delete , so here as well how i can  use primary key to delete that content,

Comment: Do you mean setting the `user_name` to a blank value? Or do you mean that you want to use to primary key `user_id` to delete the entire record instead of using the `user_name` field?

Comment: @NathanRobb i want to user user_id instead user_name

Comment: store the user id in session when user log in. then use it in delete query

Comment: Exactly, so `$sql='DELETE FROM userinfo WHERE user_id="'.$_SESSION["userid"].'"';` or something like that

Comment: I m just asking what is the use of primary key , it is better to use user_name as primary key , or in other tables we should use composite primary key, because we can't select, delete , or can't do anything using these auto generaed primary keys, is there any use of it

Comment: When you copy the primary key to new tables, do you want to copy 'some crappy long name', or a 4/8 byte number. Edit: you can use any unique value for a primary key, but small integer numbers are more (most?) efficient (RAM & CPU). And, I can't really tell what your question is - how to structure your database tables.?

Comment: @NathanRobb even if i first assign $_Session a user_id corrosponding to username like in jophab answer, i think it is better to use directly user_name for select a a query

Comment: @ABuckau I get it now, we use serial primary key only for writing them in short, they have no use beside this,

Comment: They are also unique values - primary/foreign keys are used to show connection(relationship) to data in other tables. I'd say they're useful (and help efficiency if used correctly).

Comment: @ABuckau Beside the serial primary key,,In every table we have some primary key or composite primary key , which can represent the different rows. so we can use them as primary key or composite primary key, but as you said only for write in short we use serial primary key, which can be very helpfull when we use that primary key as foreign key in other table

Comment: There can only be one "primary" key per table - no idea what you're talking about (foreign keys?)  ..is the issue resolved?

Comment: @ABuckau  i get it, my issue is resolved but i think this question does not make sense for anyone else  i should delete it

Answer (score 1):

Store the primary key value(user_id) in a session variable when user log in and use it in delete query.

For deleting a comment, make the delete link pass the primary key corresponding to that comment to the delete query.

Eg: You have a delete button,when user click on that button redirect to a php page where deletion take place

```
<a href="deletion.php?pk='put the primary key for that comment here'"><button>Delete</button></a>
```

deletion.php

You can get the primary key of that comment from `$_GET[pk]`.
Use it to delete the comment.

Make sure you check the user who is trying to delete the comment is the one who posted the comment, by using the session variables of logged in user.

This method wants a redirection from current page to delete.php and then back to current page.
If you want to avoid this use ajax to pass the values in background and refresh only the comment part of the page.

Comment: @Nanthan Robb man this is i am asking, you said "put the primary key for that comment here", just think about how i get that primary key, we have to use other columns of that table to get that primary key. and then assign corrosponding primary key value to some variable associate with particular comment, just taking the long root, so using that serial primary key has no use we can directly access that row using other columns of table, but yeah that serial primary key has very useful when we assign them as forign key in other table . otherwise that serial primary key has no use

Comment: It's not the "long root", it's the way you do things and your is about how to do it.